# Identifying small, moped-like bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, modification

I found a very cool and bizarre-looking bike in Berlin (in Germany) and was very confused about what it in fact "is"; Has anyone got an idea? — To me, it almost looks like some sort of cannibalized bike/moped/mini-motorbike hybrid:

[image: Right side]
[image: Left side]
[image: Sachs shifter]

The owner was an older guy who told me that it's "custom" but he had bought it the way it is except for the front case and Winnie-the-Pooh squeaker, which he'd added himself.

Comment: Vintage chopper bikes FTW! I know people who would be very jealous of the owner of that bike.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like 70s Schauff Elite. Compare it with bike [here](https://bonanzarad.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/schauff-elite-5/), the frame has very distinct shapes. A similar bike is also listed at the official (correct me if I'm wrong) [Schauff website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731075014/http://www.schauff.de/schauff/index.php?language=e&action=misc&ort=Intern&geschichte=3), the picture under number 28.

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I thought!